# Get destination url of youtube frontend proxy link

Tags: bash, redirect, youtube

We need to get the destination of a url for a shell script.

Here is a sample url: `https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=mOp84mPtLg7Wn3WhmrMrXzmskD58MTU3MTc5NDgwMEAxNTcxNzA4NDAw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitter.com%2FMicrosoftDE&event=channel_description`

We need to get: `https://twitter.com/MicrosoftDE` from this, as it redirects to here.

Using curl and checking headers says `p3p: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."` and we do not see `Location: https://twitter.com/MicrosoftDE`

Comment: Sorry it is not clear, do you want to get specific values from a url, correct? If yes then what are the rules/logic to get it, kindly do let us know on same.

Comment: Hello @RavinderSingh13 I want to get the url itself. I am not sure what to do in order to get the twitter url from the youtube redirecting url, that's why i am asking (:

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 echo "https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=mOp84mPtLg7Wn3WhmrMrXzmskD58MTU3MTc5NDgwMEAxNTcxNzA4NDAw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitter.com%2FMicrosoftDE&event=channel_description"| grep -o "=https.*"| sed 's/%2F/\//g'| sed 's/%3A/:/g'| sed 's/^.//'| sed 's/&.*//'
```

Explanation:
we can get url which starts with =https

Comment: use your logic instead of `echo`

Comment: This works but I was more looking for something like this. So if you use `curl` you can see the destination of a redirecting link, example `https://⁤bit⁤.ly/1kvstdE` will tell you `Location: https://google.de` when  using `curl`. Thats what I am looking for

Comment: If you want to follow redirections with `curl` then use option `-L`